# return result of async function in synchronous function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-marked

I am implementing a custom render function for [marked](https://marked.js.org/#/USING_PRO.md#renderer) which will check a few conditions on images, does an async request and then returns an image from a different source. However, since the new request is asynchronous, I will only ever get a promise back instead of a "real" image url.

`attachmentService.getBlobUrl` is an async function which does an http request and returns a promise.

My render function looks like this:

```js
marked.use({
    renderer: {
        image: (src, title, text) => {
            if (someCondition) {

                // Some code of parsing the src attribute
                // ...

                return this.attachmentService.getBlobUrl(attachment)
                    .then(url => {
                        return Promise.resolve(`<img src="${url}" alt="${text}" title="${title}"/>`)
                    })
            }

            return `<img src="${src}" alt="${text}" title="${title}"/>`
        },
    }
})
```

I already tried returning the image tag directly:

```js
// ...
return this.attachmentService.getBlobUrl(attachment)
    .then(url => {
        return `<img src="${url}" alt="${text}" title="${title}"/>`
    })
// ...
```

I have also tried wrapping the function in an `async` call and returning that (not wrapped in a `Promise.resolve`):

```js
// ...
return (async () => {
    return await this.attachmentService.getBlobUrl(attachment)
        .then(url => {
            return `<img src="${url}" alt="${text}" title="${title}"/>`
        })
})()
// ...
```

However, this also only gives me a promise.

**I cannot use `await` because the render function itself must be synchronous - that's not something I have control over.**

Comment: After a quick search: async renderers are not supported (https://github.com/markedjs/marked/issues/458)
So you'll have to write your custom renderer in a synchronous fashion.

Comment: @slhilch But how would I return the result of an async function inside of that synchronous render function?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in Javascript. You'll have to write that `getBlobUrl ` synchronous as well.

Comment: `getBlobUrl` is an http request and, by design, asynchronous. I'm afraid I can't make it synchronous. So no luck then?

Comment: You could do synchronous HTTP requests but they are deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request

Answer (score 1):

You can defer your asynchronous operation:

1. In your custom renderer, just add some unique `class` name to the img elements that should be treated differently. You could also change the `src` attribute to some loading image.
2. Then, before any of these elements are getting rendered, create a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and only listen for those elements getting added. In the MutationObserver's callback you can then perform your asynchronous operation and update the element's `src`.

Comment: That's kind of what I ended up doing. I didn't add a `MutationObserver` but instead modified the src element of the `img` directly. All within Vuejs' `this.$nextTick()` which ensures the changes are made before the elements are rendered.

Comment: See my answer below for full reference

Answer (score 0):

> the render function itself must be synchronous

Then it is not possible to use an asynchronous function like `getBlobUrl` in there. You can never make this work, it's completely impossible.

Instead, you will need to redesign your approach. Evaluate the conditions and do the async requests *before* calling `marked`. Then pass in the data that you can render synchronously.

Comment: Making requests to get the data before is not really possible since I don't know what I requests I need to make beforehand

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a new `class` to the `img` elements requiring special treatment and looped over them after the markdown was compiled to html:

```js
marked.use({
    renderer: {
        image: (src, title, text) => {

            title = title ? ` title="${title}` : ''

            if (someCondition) {
                return `<img data-src="${src}" alt="${text}" ${title} class="attachment-image"/>`
            }

            return `<img src="${src}" alt="${text}" ${title}/>`
        },
    }
})

this.preview = DOMPurify.sanitize(marked(this.text))

// Since the render function is synchronous, we can't do async http requests in it.
// Therefore, we can't resolve the blob url at (markdown) compile time.
// To work around this, we modify the url after rendering it in the vue component.
// We're doing the whole thing in the next tick to ensure the image elements are
// available in the dom tree. If we're calling this right after setting this.preview 
// it could be the images were already made available.
this.$nextTick(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('attachment-image').forEach(img => {

        // ...
        // some code ...
        // ...

        this.attachmentService.getBlobUrl(attachment)
            .then(url => {
                img.src = url
            })
    })
})
```

This is happening inside a vue js component which renders `this.preview` as `v-html` to an element.

Calling this in `this.$nextTick` is needed to ensure the `img` elements are available in order to make modifications to them.

This solution is kind of what @shilch proposed, but more "vue-y" I guess.